# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ONESPEKS.SAM_SENARAI_SEMAK_PK) violated

Tags: java, oracle

I'm using JSP, Java spring to insert the data by the user into the database.
The PK is auto generated by database. The data input by the user will inserted into datagrid, and the user will click "Save" and then it will transfer the all the datas (many rows/list) into the database.

```java
public List<SamSenaraiSemak> saveSenaraiSemak(List<SamSenaraiSemak> semak) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO SAM_SENARAI_SEMAK "
        + "(SAM_JENISURUSNIAGA_PKID,KOD,PERIHAL,ID_SIMPAN,TKH_SIMPAN,ID_SAH_SIMPAN,TKH_SAH_SIMPAN,KOD_STATUS_TRANSAKSI_PKID,STATUSFL)"
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSQL, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
            try {
                SamSenaraiSemak sam = semak.get(i);

                preparedStatement.setLong(1, sam.getJenis_urusniaga() != null ? sam.getJenis_urusniaga() : 0);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, sam.getKod() != null ? sam.getKod() : "");
                preparedStatement.setString(3, sam.getPerihal() != null ? sam.getPerihal() : "");
                preparedStatement.setLong(4, sam.getIdSimpan() != null ? sam.getIdSimpan() : 0);
                preparedStatement.setDate(5, sam.getTarikhSimpan());
                preparedStatement.setLong(6, sam.getIdSahsimpan() != null ? sam.getIdSahsimpan() : 0);
                preparedStatement.setDate(7, sam.getTarikhSahsimpan());
                preparedStatement.setLong(8, sam.getKodStatusTransaksiPkid() != null ? sam.getKodStatusTransaksiPkid() : 0);
                preparedStatement.setInt(9, sam.getStatusFL() != 0 ? sam.getStatusFL() : 0);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return semak.size();
        }
    });

    return semak;
}
```

and the Primary Key (the auto-generated one) is 1st column in database.
SAM_JENISURUSNIAGA_PKID is 2nd column.

Comment: If primary key is auto generated why do you need this? `preparedStatement.setLong(1, sam.getJenis_urusniaga() != null ? sam.getJenis_urusniaga() : 0);`

Comment: it is a unique key. The PK is sam.getPkid()